# How to transform a "pimp" method to accept a tuple?

Tags: scala, function

```
val t = (0f, 0f)

def g(x: Float, y: Float): Unit = {
  println(s"g($x, $y)")
}

g(1, 1)
(g _).tupled(t) // working

implicit class Pimps[A <: Object](a: A) {
  def f(x: Float, y: Float): A = {
    println(s"f($x, $y)")
    a
  }
}

"".f(1, 1)
("".f _).tupled(t) // not working
```

This behaviour seems very confusing and inconsistent to me. I am getting:

```
a.sc:18: missing argument list for method f in class Pimps
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `f _` or `f(_,_)` instead of `f`.
val res_6 = ("".f _).tupled(t) // not working
                ^
Compilation Failed
```

**Why** is it working in the first case and not in the second?

**How** to fix the line "not working" so function can be called with a tuple parameter without destructuring the tuple (meaning without using `._1`, `._2` or `match`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

This looks like [SI-8299](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8299)

---

This feels like a bug to me. If we simplify a bit and instantiate the implicit class explicitly, the following works:

```
implicit class Pimps(a: String) {
  def f(x: Float, y: Float): String = a
}

(new Pimps("").f _).tupled // works
```

Looking at the -Ytyper-debug output for `("".f _).tupled`:

```
|-- ("".f: (() => <empty>)).tupled : pt=Unit EXPRmode (site: method main in Implicit)
|    |    |    |    |-- ("".f: (() => <empty>)) EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: method main in Implicit)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- "" EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: method main in Implicit)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> String("")
|    |    |    |    |    [search #1] start `""`, searching for adaptation to pt=String("") => ?{def f: ?} (silent: method main in Implicit) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    [search #1] considering Pimps
|    |    |    |    |    |-- Pimps BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: method main in Implicit) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> (a: String)Pimps
|    |    |    |    |    [search #1] success inferred value of type String("") => ?{def f: ?} is SearchResult(Pimps, )
|    |    |    |    |    |-- (a: String)Pimps EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (silent: method main in Implicit)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> Pimps
|    |    |    |    |    |-- Pimps("").f EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (site: method main in Implicit)
Implicit.scala:21: error: missing argument list for method f in class Pimps
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `f _` or `f(_,_)` instead of `f`.
    ("".f _).tupled
```

While the compiler resolves the implicit class properly, but then reaches the method definition and fails.

You can work around this by either using type ascription:

```
("".f: (Float, Float) => String).tupled
```

Or by binding the function to a typed value:

```
val func: (Float, Float) => String = "".f
func.tupled
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **How** part:

```
("".f(_, _)).tupled(t)
```

Another options which is technically valid (although I know you meant something else) is:

```
val (x, y) = t // destructuring, but not using ._1, ._2 or match
"".f(x, y)
```

---

**Edit for future reference**:

Regarding the **Why** part:
Yuval found that this is a bug - reported at [SI-8299](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8299)

So to summarize, you can dodge this by specifying the type with type ascription/binding the function to a type value as Yuval suggested, or expanding with `.f(_, _)`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. There is no syntax error with his code,he's eta expanding a method to a function value.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you are correct. I am not sure in which part of the compilation the compiler emits this error.
I edited my post and left the how part for now.